# Recursive function called in setTimeout is executing even after navigated to other Angular components

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, angular6, settimeout

It became challenging for me to stop executing a recursive function that is used to display a progress bar even after navigating to different component.

```
animateProgress() {
    var counter = this.incrementCounter;    //initial value = 0
    if (counter <= 100) {
      this.updateProgressBar(counter);
      setTimeout(()=>{  
        this.animateProgress();   
      }, 3000);
      this.incrementCounter++;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
updateProgressBar(percentage) {
    $('.progressBarDiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're never calling `clearTimeout` anywhere so of course it continues to run?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you post the whole class, including where you call `animateProgress()`

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `setInterval` since you want that part of code to be repeated multiple times.

```
animateProgress() {
    // removed the local variable counter cause it wasn't really necessary

    // setInterval returns an id that you can later use to cancel the interval
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.incrementCounter <= 100) {
          this.updateProgressBar();
          this.incrementCounter++;
        }
        else {
            // when you reach the condition you clear the inverval
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 3000);
}

updateProgressBar() {
    $('.progressBarDiv').css("width", this.incrementCounter + "%");
}
```

Otherwise if you wish to stick with setTimeout and recursion this whould work:

```
animateProgress() {
    if (this.incrementCounter <= 100) {
      this.updateProgressBar();
      this.incrementCounter++;
      setTimeout(()=>{  
        this.animateProgress();   
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
```